# Advantage of fewer processors in ForkJoin

Tags: java, parallel-processing, fork-join

I have been seeing how changing the number of processors used in a program that uses Java's ForkJoin for parallelization affects other processes going on with my computer (such as web browsing, typing a paper, opening other files). I had thought before that using fewer processors would leave more processing power for other tasks that my computer is doing, but I do not notice any difference in these tasks when I use one processor versus the maximum number of processors. Why would one ever want to use one processor rather than the maximum number of processors?